# CSS background position based on class name

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 8 icons in total, 4 blue and 4 grey. So product 1 has a blue icon and also has a grey icon.

When I have product 1 - user will see a blue icon (added class on container to say .gotProduct)
when I don't have product 1 - user will see a grey icon (added class on container to say .noProduct)

However in my CSS I can't seem to get the icons showing:
http://jsfiddle.net/m09zecj4/3/

The same for when I have and don't have product 2 and so on.

```
<section class="panel productPillar productTwo gotProduct">
  <span class="productImg"></span>
  <p>this should be blue with a 2</p>
</section>
```

Fiddle will shed more light on what I am trying to achieve!

Comment: you added .noProduct but where did you use it in css?you have two classes but you are not changing image based on that.you have image  in product pillar class.it wont change unless you have them in gotProduct and noProduct classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your icons are showing perfectly fine.. the problem is that your squares are way too small.. I fixed this in this:

```
.productPillar  {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnDR0.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 300px; /* Made this larger*/
    height: 300px; /* Made this larger*/
    display: block;
    zoom:1.0;   
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

If you would still like the sqares to be small then you should amend the background position of your classes accordingly..

**Edit:**

The correct way of doing this is without the inner `<span>`. I've removed it and changed the CSS accordingly. Also, you might have confused the x and y axis of the background image so I fixed it.

new [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m09zecj4/6/)

Comment: cheers, however if the class of .noProduct the 2nd box should be grey. And if i have .productTwo, this should display the blue and grey box with the number 2 in it and so on, all depends on .productOne .gotProduct / .no Product and same for products 2,3 and 4?

Comment: @John ofcourse sorry one sec

Comment: thats just using the image from .productPillar i need to set the background position differently if they have / dont have the product or dependant on what product number they have as well

Answer (score 1):

Because you are changing the `background-position` on the .productImg class, you also have to define the background on the .productImg class.

```
.productImg {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnDR0.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 155px;
    height: 155px;
    display: block;
    zoom:1.0;   
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/m09zecj4/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

```css
.productImg  {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnDR0.png);
    width: 292px;
    height: 298px;
    display: block;
    zoom:1.0;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
 border:1px solid red;
}

/*PRODUCT ONE should display a blue / grey icon with a 1 on it*/
.productOne.noProduct span.productImg{
    background-position:-18px -376px;
}

.productOne.gotProduct span.productImg{
    background-position:-18px -28px;
}

/*PRODUCT TWO - should display blue / grey icon with a 2 on it*/
.productTwo.noProduct span.productImg{
    background-position:-371px -376px;
}

.productTwo.gotProduct span.productImg{
    background-position:-371px -28px;
}
```

```html
<h1> Product One </h1>
<section class="panel productPillar productOne gotProduct">
      <span class="productImg"></span>
    <p>this should be blue with a 1</p>
</section>

<section class="panel productPillar productOne noProduct">
      <span class="productImg"></span>
    <p>this should be grey with a 1</p>
</section>

<hr />
<h1> Product Two </h1>
<section class="panel productPillar productTwo gotProduct">
      <span class="productImg"></span>
    <p>this should be blue with a 2</p>
</section>

<section class="panel productPillar productTwo noProduct">
      <span class="productImg"></span>
    <p>this should be grey with a 2</p>
</section>
```